# Assist me in this error here

Tags: c#

I have to make a small program that prompts the user test mark and determines if the user has passed or failed. A test mark less than 50 is a fail.

Here is the code I have. It gives me 2 errors (which have stars in them.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Prac6Question2
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double testMark;
            string result;

            testMark = GetTestMark(*testMark*);
            result = DetermineResult(testMark, *result*);
            Display(testMark, result); 

        }

        static double GetTestMark(double testMark)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your test result: ");
            testMark = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return testMark;

        }

        static string DetermineResult(double testMark, string result)
        {
            if (testMark < 50)
                result = "Fail";
            else
                result = "Pass";

            return result;

        }

        static void Display(double testMark, string result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your test result: {0}", result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You have errors eh? What are they? First problem I see is that you're passing in uninstantiated variables.

Comment: You have two uninitiliazed locals in `main`. The quick fix is to initialize them before passing them to your other methods. The better fix is to refactor and not pass in the *output* variable as an *input* to the helper method that is meant to return its value.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass those values to their respective functions. Remove the parameters and introduce new variables in the functions.

```
testMark = GetTestMark();
result = DetermineResult(testMark);
```

Answer (score 1):

- testMark & result are not assigned yet when you use them

Answer (score 1):

In order to have `GetTestMark` change the value in the caller's scope, you would need to pass the double by reference, ie:

```
static void GetTestMark(out double testMark)
```

The "out" specifies that the value will be initialized in this method.

Then call it via:

```
GetTestMark(out testMark);
```

However, since you're returning the value, you don't need to pass it at all:

```
static double GetTestMark()
{
   double testMark; // Declare a local
   Console.WriteLine("Your test result: ");
   testMark = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   return testMark;
}
```

And call via:

```
testMark = GetTestMark();
```

Result is the same way - since you're returning the value, there is no reason to pass it.  The same type of change as above will cause it to work properly, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, what you have starred should be deleted.  You are passing in a variable that you don't use, and the compiler is most likely complaining about uninitialized variables

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Prac6Question2
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double testMark;
            string result;

            testMark = GetTestMark();
            result = DetermineResult(testMark);
            Display(testMark, result); 

        }

        static double GetTestMark()
        {
            double testMark;
            Console.WriteLine("Your test result: ");
            testMark = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return testMark;

        }

        static string DetermineResult(double testMark)
        {
            string result;
            if (testMark < 50)
                result = "Fail";
            else
                result = "Pass";

            return result;

        }

        static void Display(double testMark, string result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your test result: {0}", result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```